# Правильная остановка потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Добрый день.
Имеется нативный винапи поток, создаваемый функцией CreateThread(..). Поток опрашивает железо и иногда, когда железо глючит, то поток виснет и возникает необходимость его убить. Для убийства потока используется следующий код:

```
if (thread != NULL && thread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD dwProcRet = STILL_ACTIVE;
    GetExitCodeThread(thread, &dwProcRet);

    if (dwProcRet == STILL_ACTIVE && WaitForSingleObject(thread, 1000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        if (TerminateThread(thread, 0) == 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

Достаточен ли данный код для убийства потоков?

P.S. TerminateThread опасная функция и я знаю об этом, именно поэтому сам поток не владеет никакими ресурсами (файлы/сокеты и т.д) и не использует синхронизацию с другими потоками (чтобы избежать deadlock'ов). К сожалению производитель железа выдает апи в статусе "как есть" и разреверсить его пока не удалось.

Comment: GetExitCodeProcess работает с процессом, а не с тредом.

Comment: Это наверное опечатка, там `GetExitCodeThread` должно быть.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, закралась опечатка GetExitCodeThread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прерывание потока вызовом `TerminateThread` переводит ваше приложение в несогласованное состояние. Другими словами, после такого вызова оно должно сразу аварийно завершать работу, может сделав дамп для отладочных целей. Если хочется как-то выкрутиться из подвисшего состояния, то следует вынести проблемный код в отдельный процесс и убивать этот процесс посредством `TerminateProcess`. Тогда ваше основное приложение сможет продолжать работать.

Comment: Сомнительно мне это: если поток только и делает, что шлет данные в порт - как его остановка будет влиять на остальную программу?

Comment: Вот меня интересует эта несогласованное состояние. Поток изолирован от всего. Т.е. на уровне своей программы я даю 100% гарантию, что убийство потока не вызовет рассогласованности.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Вы же сами пишете *"Поток опрашивает железо"*, следовательно он должен (как минимум) осуществлять какой-то ввод/вывод, следовательно никакой почвы для давания гарантий такого рода у вас нет.

Comment: @VTT, почему нет, суть несогласованного состояния в появлении каких-либо незакрытых дескрипторов или локов синхронизации. Поток это не делает. Весь ввод/вывод использует уже существующие (открытые извне потока) ресурсы, жизнью которых управляет уже абсолютно другая сущность.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Практически любая операция ввода/вывода может включать синхроницию, динамическое выделение памяти, вызовы функций ядра и разных динамических библиотек. Короче говоря вы получаете полный букет проблем, перечисленных на [странице MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @goldstar_labs: Ваш поток ни от чего не изолирован, он пользуется тем же рантаймом. Любая внутренняя функция может вызвать malloc/new, который может висеть в heap lock на момент убийства потока. Или может грузиться DLL, и поток будет держать loader lock. И так далее. Подход «дайте мне список вообще всех возможных проблем, я их буду обходить одну за одной» в корне неправильный. Список потенциальных проблем бесконечен. Убивать поток _нельзя_. Единицей изоляции является процесс, пользуйтесь отдельным процессом.

Comment: @VladD, да оборачивание в процессы это верное решение, я тут даже не спорю, но оно подразумевает очень много дополнительного кода для организации ipc и управления, а времени как всегда нет) Спасибо за ответы, буду искать компромисс между надежностью и затратами на реализацию.

Comment: @goldstar_labs: Ну это да. Прагматически, можно убивать поток для быстрого решения с возможностью дедлоков, и сразу же писать  апгрейд/сервис пак, с заменой на процесс :-)